# jquery assign value to key via .data() not working

Tags: jquery

I have a pretty straightforward (one would think) task.

Pass a value to a popup window and based on a click (proceed or cancel) perform an action using the value passed.

```
    // on click we pass the value to the function testing - so far so good
$('#numbers').delegate('.icondelete', 'click', function(){
    testing( $(this).attr('data-options') ); 
});
```

I pass the value found to a function, then try to assign it to a key

```
function testing(id){
   //we can see that it passed successfully
    alert("here it is: " + id); 

     //push the data into key data-id
    $('#dodelete').data('data-id',id);

//but this alert doesn't return the value
alert("it should be here shouldn't it? " + $('#dodelete').attr('data-id'));
    }
```

html

```
<div id='numbers' >
<div class='icondelete'  data-options='123' >Set data-options as 123 - click here to test</div>
</div>

<br><br>
<div id='dodelete' data-id=''>landing div</div>
```

If you check out the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Microbe/cRLfC/4/ , you can see that the value is passed into the function no probs, but then when I try to assign it to the key it doesn't.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When using `.data()`, do not add the `data-` prefix.  When reading a value back, use `.data("key")`, not `.attr()`.  I'd suggest reading [this](http://api.jquery.com/data/) and looking at the code examples.

So your code should look like this:

```
function testing(id) {
   //we can see that it passed successfully
    alert("here it is: " + id); 

     //push the data into key myid
    $('#dodelete').data('myid', id);

    //but this alert doesn't return the value
    alert("it should be here shouldn't it? " + $('#dodelete').data('myid'));
}
```

Settings values via `.data()` does not actually set an attribute/property on the object with that value.  The data is actually stored inside a jQuery data structure and it is retrieved not with `.attr("key")`, but with `.data("key")`.

If you want to set an actual attribute, do that with `.attr("key", value)`, though in jQuery coding, it's generally better to use `.data()` than custom attributes.

The only time you would use the `data-` prefix yourself is if you put a custom attribute in your HTML like this per the HTML5 standard for custom attributes:

```
<div id="myObject" data-numloops="20"></div>
```

Then, you could read that with this:

```
var loopCnt = $("#myObject").data("numloops");
```

When querying the data value, jQuery will first look in its own internal storage.  If not found there, it will look for an HTML5 data attribute that matches the name.

Comment: aha - yep, that is it.  So...can you explain why?  I thought .attr() returned the value of that key

Comment: `.attr()` returns the value of an attribute on the object.  `.data()` does not store its data as the attribute of an object - it stores it in an internal cache - thus you cannot set with `.data()` and read with `.attr()`.  You set things with `.data(key, value)`, you read them with `.data(key)`.  That's how jQuery `.data()` works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like this implementation since on one hand it reads the 'data-xxx' attributes but on the other hand it does not write it. Just for the ease of having a cache and being able to store objects and functions.

This is called 'programming with side effects'. It's confusing and it's mixing up two different concepts which interfere with each other. I think that's a strictly 'no go'. There are other ways of linking objects to a DOM element - mainly by the use of event handlers which should cover most use cases. Complex data which is dependent on 'states' should be placed as members in objects and that should do the remaining use cases. Put the object in the event handler's data and you have everything you need. That's the approach of 'OOP'. It works in C++, C# and in Java and there is no reason why it should not work in JavaScript. It has a much lesser chance of memory leaks or inconsistent data.

So please: don't use these features. Don't even think about it. Better study OOP-patterns and do it good right from the start!

Comment: Well, maybe you are right, but for sure you are not answering the question. Stackoverflow is not right place to express your opinion. Please, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers namely: as *Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question* are treated if **not even a partial answer to the actual question**